# Getting animation height during animation in Swift / iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying to get the current height of an animated `UIView` on my app.

I animate the `UIView` using:

```
function startFilling() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0, options: CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.filler.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)
    }) { (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            self.removeGestureRecognizer(self.tap)
            self.delegate?.showSuccessLabel!()
        } else if !success {
            print("Not successful")
        }
    }
}
```

This animation is triggered using the `.Begin` state of a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` like so:

```
if press.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
    startFilling()
} else if press.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
    endFilling()
}
```

If the user stops pressing then the function `endFilling` is called and I need to get the current height of `self.filler` at the time they stop pressing.

The trouble is that the height always returns the expected end height in the animation (eg. `self.frame.height`), even if the press only lasted a portion of the duration time.

How can I get this height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not really how core animation works. Once you set a animatable value in a UIView.animateWithDuration block that value is set, whether the animation is completed or not. Thus when you ask for `self.filler.frame` after you call startFilling it is equal to `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)` regardless of whether it's 0.5 seconds or 5.0 seconds after you call startFilling. If you want to get the current value of the frame for what is on the screen, you need to say `self.filler.layer.presentationLayer.frame`. This should be used as a readonly value. If you want to interrupt the animation and have it come to rest at this value, you should say something like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0, options: BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        self.filler.frame = self.layer.filler.presentationLayer.frame
    })
```

Comment: Hey @beyowulf - I've edited the answer to slightly modify the `self.filler.layer...` piece to what I did as presentationLayer is a function not a property.  Thanks heaps :)

Comment: @bwash70 shouldn't it be `self.filler.layer.presentationLayer().frame` and not `self.layer.filler.presentationLayer.frame`?

Answer (score 2):

In swift4

self.filler.layer.presentation().bounds